# ireport print on infinite paper on data matrix printer

Tags: pdf, printing, pagination, jasper-reports, infinite

I am using iReport and I have a report that has multiple subreports.
For the purpose of using matrix printer (EPSON), report has to be printed as one infinite document.

When ignore pagination is set to true the pdf is empty (in iReport the preview is ok).

Any suggestions??

thank you

my jrxml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="zapkuverta1" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="540" leftMargin="35" rightMargin="20" topMargin="5" bottomMargin="20">
        <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.1269722013523666"/>
        <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
        <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
        <subDataset name="dataset1">
            <queryString>
                <![CDATA[SELECT ve_id_ve
    FROM verzije]]>
            </queryString>
            <field name="ve_id_ve" class="java.lang.Integer">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
        </subDataset>
        <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Kapla\\izpisi\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="_criteria" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>
        <parameter name="_logo" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["\\logo-petrol.jpg"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="_username" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Username"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="_ip" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["IpAddr"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="_company" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["Company"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="_schema" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["public."]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["IS NULL OR 1=1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["IS NULL OR 1=1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["IS NULL OR 1=1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <parameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe" class="java.lang.String">
            <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["IS NULL OR 1=1"]]></defaultValueExpression>
        </parameter>
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[SELECT
        dmzaposlenih.dmz_izplacilnamesta as "izplacilnamesta",
        dmzaposlenih.dmz_orgenote as "orgenote",
        verzijazaposleni.vz_stmesta as "strmesta",
        zaposleni.za_polnoime as "polnoime",
        zaposleni.za_id_za as "idzaposlenega",
        naslovi.na_naslov as "naslov_zaposlenega",
        naslovi.na_posta as "posta_zaposlenega",
        posta.pos_naziv as "naziv_poste_zaposlenega",
        verzijazaposleni.vz_vsadeldoba AS "vz_vsadeldoba",
        verzijazaposleni.vz_deldobapod AS "vz_deldobapod",
        verzijazaposleni.vz_procmdd AS "vz_procmdd",
        (
            select  podjetja.pod_naziv from $P!{_schema}podjetja AS podjetja
        ) as  "kratkinaziv",

        (
            SELECT podjetja.pod_naslov from $P!{_schema}podjetja AS podjetja
        ) as "naslov",
        (
            SELECT podjetja.pod_posta from $P!{_schema}podjetja AS podjetja
        ) as "posta",

        (
            SELECT posta.pos_naziv from $P!{_schema}podjetja AS podjetja

                INNER JOIN

                    $P!{_schema}posta AS posta

                ON

                podjetja.pod_posta = posta.pos_id_pos
        ) as "imeposte",
        verzije.ve_id_ve AS "verzija",
        verzije.ve_datizp AS "ve_datizp",
        verzije.ve_datnamena AS "ve_datnamena",
        CAST(verzije.ve_datnamena as CHAR(6))   AS "ve_datnamenamesc"
    FROM
            (SELECT
            a.*
        FROM
            $P!{_schema}dmzaposlenih AS a
        INNER JOIN
            (SELECT
                dmz_zaposleni,
                MAX(COALESCE(dmz_datumdo,'9999-12-31')) AS max_dmz_datumdo
            FROM
                $P!{_schema}dmzaposlenih
            GROUP BY
                dmz_zaposleni) AS b
        ON
            a.dmz_zaposleni = b.dmz_zaposleni
            AND COALESCE(a.dmz_datumdo,'9999-12-31') = b.max_dmz_datumdo) as dmzaposlenih

    INNER JOIN
        $P!{_schema}zaposleni AS zaposleni

    ON
        dmzaposlenih.dmz_zaposleni = zaposleni.za_id_za

    INNER JOIN
        $P!{_schema}verzijazaposleni AS verzijazaposleni
    ON
        zaposleni.za_id_za = verzijazaposleni.vz_zaposleni

    INNER JOIN
        $P!{_schema}verzije AS verzije
    ON
        verzijazaposleni.vz_verzije = verzije.ve_id_ve

    INNER JOIN
        $P!{_schema}verzijastrmesta AS verzijastrmesta
    ON
        verzijazaposleni.vz_stmesta =verzijastrmesta.vs_strmesta
        --dmzaposlenih.dmz_strmesta = verzijastrmesta.vs_strmesta
        AND verzijazaposleni.vz_verzije = verzijastrmesta.vs_verzije


    INNER JOIN
        $P!{_schema}verzijaorgenote verzijaorgenote
    ON
        vo_verzije = vz_verzije
        AND vo_orgenote = dmz_orgenote

    INNER JOIN
        $P!{_schema}naslovi AS naslovi
    ON
        naslovi.na_zaposleni = zaposleni.za_id_za

    INNER JOIN
        $P!{_schema}posta AS posta
    ON
        naslovi.na_posta = posta.pos_id_pos


    WHERE
        1=1
        AND (za_id_za $P!{zaposleni.za_id_za})
        AND (ve_id_ve $P!{verzije.ve_id_ve})
        AND (verzijazaposleni.vz_stmesta  $P!{strmesta.sm_id_sm})
        AND (dmzaposlenih.dmz_orgenote  $P!{orgenote.oe_id_oe})
        AND (za_id_za in (SELECT distinct vpl_zaposleni from $P!{_schema}verzijaplaca
                where 1=1
                AND (vpl_zaposleni $P!{zaposleni.za_id_za})
                AND (vpl_verzije $P!{verzije.ve_id_ve})))

    ORDER BY
        dmzaposlenih.dmz_izplacilnamesta,
        dmzaposlenih.dmz_orgenote,
        verzijazaposleni.vz_stmesta,
        zaposleni.za_polnoime,
        zaposleni.za_id_za]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="izplacilnamesta" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="orgenote" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="strmesta" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="polnoime" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="idzaposlenega" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="naslov_zaposlenega" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="posta_zaposlenega" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="naziv_poste_zaposlenega" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="vz_vsadeldoba" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="vz_deldobapod" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="vz_procmdd" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
        <field name="kratkinaziv" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="naslov" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="posta" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="imeposte" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="verzija" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="ve_datizp" class="java.sql.Date"/>
        <field name="ve_datnamena" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
        <field name="ve_datnamenamesc" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <group name="zaposleni">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{zaposleni_COUNT}]]></groupExpression>
            <groupHeader>
                <band height="280" splitType="Stretch">
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="-1" y="246" width="535" height="1"/>
                    </line>
                    <subreport>
                        <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToTallestObject" x="0" y="154" width="535" height="92" printWhenGroupChanges="zaposleni"/>
                        <subreportParameter name="_schema">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{verzija}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{strmesta.sm_id_sm}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{orgenote.oe_id_oe}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "zapkuvertadb2_ISKRAVZD_subreportA.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
                    <subreport>
                        <reportElement stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="248" width="535" height="15" printWhenGroupChanges="zaposleni">
                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega} != null]]></printWhenExpression>
                        </reportElement>
                        <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="_schema">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{verzija}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{strmesta.sm_id_sm}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <subreportParameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe">
                            <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{orgenote.oe_id_oe}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                        </subreportParameter>
                        <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                        <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "zapkuvertadb2_ISKRAVZD_subreportB.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                    </subreport>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="264" width="535" height="1"/>
                    </line>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="266" width="106" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Delovna doba v pod. :]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="205" y="266" width="99" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Delovna doba vsa :]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="366" y="266" width="95" height="14"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Right" lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Procent za MD:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="83" y="266" width="75" height="14"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Right" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{vz_deldobapod}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement positionType="Float" x="279" y="266" width="67" height="14"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Right" lineSpacing="Single"/>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{vz_vsadeldoba}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="61" y="61" width="5" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[-]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="442" y="39" width="7" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="172" y="61" width="270" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font isBold="true" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{polnoime}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="3" y="61" width="31" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{izplacilnamesta}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="450" y="39" width="13" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[($F{ve_datnamenamesc} != null)? ($F{ve_datnamenamesc}).substring(4,6) : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="35" y="61" width="5" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[-]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="462" y="39" width="2" height="14"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[.]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="449" y="10" width="88" height="15"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}+1]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="442" y="10" width="7" height="15"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="442" y="25" width="7" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="72" y="61" width="37" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{strmesta}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="43" y="61" width="19" height="13"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Justified" lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{orgenote}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="364" y="25" width="78" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Datum izplačila]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="449" y="25" width="88" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{ve_datizp}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="364" y="39" width="78" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Izplačilo za]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="106" y="61" width="5" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[-]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="62" y="35" width="100" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{imeposte}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="468" y="39" width="69" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[($F{ve_datnamena} != null ) ? ($F{ve_datnamena}).toString().substring(0,4) : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="172" y="74" width="219" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{naslov_zaposlenega}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="3" y="22" width="206" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{naslov}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="117" y="61" width="55" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font isBold="true" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="3" y="10" width="206" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{kratkinaziv}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="172" y="87" width="37" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{posta_zaposlenega}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="364" y="10" width="78" height="15"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Zap štev.]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="209" y="87" width="141" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{naziv_poste_zaposlenega}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                        <reportElement x="3" y="35" width="59" height="13"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{posta}]]></textFieldExpression>
                    </textField>
                </band>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
        <group name="opombe" isStartNewPage="true" isReprintHeaderOnEachPage="true">
            <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{zaposleni_COUNT}]]></groupExpression>
            <groupHeader>
                <band height="21" splitType="Stretch">
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="305" y="1" width="83" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Ure/Proc/Osnova]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="482" y="1" width="53" height="14"/>
                        <textElement textAlignment="Right" lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font isBold="true"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Znesek]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="-1" y="1" width="535" height="1"/>
                    </line>
                    <line>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="535" height="1"/>
                    </line>
                    <staticText>
                        <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="121" height="14"/>
                        <textElement lineSpacing="Single">
                            <font isBold="true" pdfEncoding="Cp1250"/>
                        </textElement>
                        <text><![CDATA[Vrsta   in   naziv plačila]]></text>
                    </staticText>
                </band>
            </groupHeader>
        </group>
        <background>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </background>
        <title>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </title>
        <pageHeader>
            <band splitType="Stretch"/>
        </pageHeader>
        <detail>
            <band height="228" splitType="Stretch">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="535" height="15" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="_schema">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{verzija}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{strmesta.sm_id_sm}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{orgenote.oe_id_oe}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "zapkuvertadb2_ISKRAVZD_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="14" width="535" height="44"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="_schema">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{verzija}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{strmesta.sm_id_sm}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{orgenote.oe_id_oe}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "zapkuvertadb2_ISKRAVZD_subreport2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="73" width="535" height="56"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="_schema">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{verzija}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{strmesta.sm_id_sm}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{orgenote.oe_id_oe}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "zapkuvertadb2_ISKRAVZD_subreport3.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="142" width="535" height="19"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="_schema">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{verzija}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{strmesta.sm_id_sm}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{orgenote.oe_id_oe}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "zapkuvertadb2_ISKRAVZD_subreport4a.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="161" width="535" height="20"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="_schema">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{verzija}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{strmesta.sm_id_sm}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{orgenote.oe_id_oe}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "zapkuvertadb2_ISKRAVZD_subreport4.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="192" width="535" height="36"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="_schema">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{_schema}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="verzije.ve_id_ve">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{verzija}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="strmesta.sm_id_sm">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{strmesta.sm_id_sm}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="zaposleni.za_id_za">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{idzaposlenega}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportParameter name="orgenote.oe_id_oe">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{orgenote.oe_id_oe}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "zapkuvertadb2_ISKRAVZD_subreport5.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
            </band>
        </detail>
    </jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you post your jrxml file?

Comment: @Yebach `When ignore pagination is set to true the pdf is empty (in iReport the preview is ok).` - Did you use the *Java* code when you got the empty file?

Comment: No I have it set on groovy, cos if I set to Java code I get an error 404 on my webapp when printing the report

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to set the page height to 880.
Ignore pagination was set to false. 
I also set start group on new page to true and in detail I inserted page break.

I tried various options and this was the only one that worked. Otherwise new page was printed to high on new page or too low and on infinite paper it all got bad after 2 or 3 pages of printing.